# Graphical multiplication tables for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, education, visualization

Inspired by Burkard Polster's beautiful video on [Times Tables, Mandelbrot and the Heart of Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhbuKbxJsk8) I wondered how this graphical approach to visualize the multiplicative structure of finite rings could be extended to infinite rings, especially to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Here are a few examples of graphical times (= multiplication) tables for $p= 11,29,97$:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Enlarged for the first numbers for $p=97$:

[image]

Note that one immediately sees that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ prime has no zero divisors: no lines end at $0$, the point at the bottom.

---

My simple idea was: Just project $\mathbb{Z}$ on the unit circle and just draw the "times tables":

[image]
[image]

Note *that* and *how* and *why* the diversity of forms for finite rings gets lost!

Note further that the $\times +n$ and $\times -n$ tables tend to look the same for $n \rightarrow \infty$:

[image]

I wonder:

1. Has this graphical approach been taken already?
2. What might its didactical/pedagogical/educational values be?
3. Mathematically: How do the graphs for finite rings – among each other and with the graph for the infinite ring $\mathbb{Z}$ – relate? (In which terms would one define such relations, how would one analyse them?)

Comment: The tables on the top for multiplication by $3$ and $4$ are identical. Have the elements been rearranged in some systematic way between the diagrams?

Comment: Which ones exactly do you mean?

Comment: For $p=11$ the ones labelled as $\times 3$ and as $\times 4$ are identical.

Comment: Actually, they are identical in pairs, so something has gone wrong.

Comment: Not really: $3 \times 4 \mod 11 = 1$ so there is a line from $3$ to $1$ in the $\times 4$ table. But there is also a line from $1$ to $3$ in the $\times 3$ table - obviously. The problem so is that the direction of the lines is not indicated: with arrow heads, the two tables would not be identical.

Comment: But it's nevertheless an interesting observation, isn't it?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You might be interested in this other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990119/isomorphic-multiplication-tables-for-mathbbz-p-mathbbz

Comment: ... which already has a definite answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2990167/1792