# Isomorphic multiplication tables for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Two (undirected) [multiplication graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988910/graphical-multiplication-tables-for-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-and-mathbbz) $n$, $m$ for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ look the same ($n \sim_p m$) when

$$a n= b\operatorname{mod} p \ \ \text{ iff }\ \ b m  = a \operatorname{mod} p$$

for all $a,b < p$. This is the case for $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ and

- $n =2, m = 6$
- $n =3, m = 4$
- $n =5, m = 9$
- $n =7, m = 8$

[image]

For $\mathbb{Z}/29\mathbb{Z}$ we find

- $2 \sim_{29} 15$
- $3 \sim_{29} 10$
- $4 \sim_{29} 22$
- $5 \sim_{29} 6$
- $7 \sim_{29} 25$
- $8 \sim_{29} 11$
- $9 \sim_{29} 13$
- $12 \sim_{29} 17$
- $14 \sim_{29} 27$
- $16 \sim_{29} 20$
- $18 \sim_{29} 21$
- $19 \sim_{29} 26$
- $23 \sim_{29} 24$

[image]

Some observations:

- $p-1 \not\sim_p n$ for all $n < p-1$
- For both $p=11$ and $p=29$ all $n,m < p-1$ come in pairs. Maybe for all $p$? Or possibly larger equivalence classes for ever larger $p$? (Only even tupels, only $2^k$-tupels?)
- For both $p=11$ and $p=29$ there are two consecutive pairs: $3,4$ and $7,8$ resp. $5,6$ and $23,24$. The first located more close to $1$, the second somehow symmetric and more close to $p-1$. Maybe for all $p$? Or possibly more than two for ever larger $p$? Or longer consecutive sequences?

My question is:

> What's the general pattern? Which $n,m < p$ are equivalent in the
>   sense above, i.e. $n \sim_p m$?

Comment: Have you seen the discussion in Daniel Shanks's textbook [Solved and Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Solved-Unsolved-Problems-Number-Theory/dp/0828412979) ?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I surely will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your definition of $n \sim_p m$:
$$a\cdot n \bmod p = b\ \ \text{ iff }\ \ b\cdot m \bmod p = a$$

Take $a=m$. Then
$$m\cdot n \bmod p = b\ \ \text{ iff }\ \ b\cdot m \bmod p = m$$
The second equation holds iff $b \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and then the first equation gives $mn \equiv 1 \bmod p$.

Bottom line:
$$
n \sim_p m \ \text{ iff }\ mn \equiv 1 \bmod p
$$

Comment: To say it otherwise: $n \sim_p m $ iff $n = m^{-1}$, i.e. $n$ and $m$ are inverses of each other.